# How can I log a user in automatically after creating their account on the server in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to have my user automatically logged into their account after the sign up process.  Since I am using the alanning:roles package, I need to create the user on the server in order to apply the roles.

In my Meteor method, I have the following account code:

```
createClient: function (user) {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        check(user, {
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String,
            email: String,
            phone: String
        });
        var newUser = Accounts.createUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            profile: {
                firstName: user.firstName,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                phone: user.phone,
                created: new Date()
            }
        });
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(newUser, ['client']);
        return Meteor.users.findOne(newUser);
    }
}
```

Then, within the callback, I login the user:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(newUser._id, newUser.profile.tempPassword, function (error) {
    Router.go('thenextpage');
});
```

When I do this, it takes me to the next page, but does not log the user in.  Occasionally, I get an error in the browser console that says: `error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again. [403]`

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the account on the client, then use `Accounts.onCreateUser` on the server to add the roles in:

//Client side

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email: user.email,
  password: user.password,
  profile: {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      phone: user.phone,
      created: new Date()
  }
}, function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

//Server side:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

    user.roles = ["client"];

    if (options.profile)
        user.profile = options.profile;
    return user;
});
```

So how this works is we directly assign the `client` role. So long as the role exists in the `Meteor.roles` collection you will not have an issue & will not have to call `Roles.addUsersToRoles`.